# Tengo un problema : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Insuficiente heap space

Tags: java, array, arraylist, out-of-memory-error, heap

Me compré una notebook nueva le instalé java jdk 8 y jre 8, puse el path  correctamente. Instale otras veces java y nunca tuve este problema antes.
Cuando corro un metodo bastante basico me salta este error

```
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at modelo.Sistema.comparaLista(Sistema.java:111)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:25)***
```

Entiendo que es algun problema en la memoria,probé cambiarle los argumentos por -Xmx256M
-Xmn16m etc.
Probé varios pero sigue igual, peor hace un ruido que parece que va explotar y es nueva!
**HP core i3 4gb ram** (fué lo mejor que pude comprar), nose a quien recurrir.
Espero que puedan ayudarme. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes compartir el código en forma de texto, no como imagen, para que lo podamos reproducir. El problema no lo tiene la computadora nueva. Ese error te indica que se está quedando sin espacio para seguir instanciando objetos, lo más probable es que el algoritmo del método `compararLista` sea muy ineficiente. No se ve todo el código del método y tampoco se puede deducir lo que hace, no tiene valor de retorno, solo asumimos que compara las listas pero no sabemos a qué conclusión debería llegar o qué debería hacer. Edita el post y comparte el código y explica un poco lo que consideres necesario.

Comment: @GlennSandoval Tenias razón el código es ineficiente, cambie de computadora en donde no tendría que haber ningún tipo de problema y me lanzó el mismo error. Cambie todo lo dividí en distintos métodos y funcionó bien.

Comment: me da alto cringe de ver tu codigo, ponlo como texto y te muestro el monton de partes donde se puede optimizar tu metodo `comparaLista`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El esquema de gestión de memoria de la JVM reserva una parte de la memoria del montón para almacenar objetos recién asignados. Todos los objetos a los que se hace referencia permanecen activos en el montón a lo largo de su vida útil (hasta que se cierra su referencia) y ocupan memoria. Cuando ya no se hace referencia a los objetos, se vuelven elegibles para que el GC los elimine y libere la memoria del montón ocupada.

El tamaño del almacenamiento dinámico de Java está determinado por dos atributos de JVM, que se pueden configurar al iniciar Java:

- -Xms para establecer el tamaño de almacenamiento dinámico inicial
- -Xmx para establecer el tamaño máximo de almacenamiento dinámico

La cantidad de memoria de almacenamiento dinámico utilizada por una aplicación Java afecta la cantidad de objetos que se pueden asignar y su tamaño. Si un objeto requiere más memoria de la que está disponible en el montón, la aplicación puede encontrar un java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Un java.lang.OutOfMemoryError generalmente significa que algo está mal en la aplicación; por ejemplo, el código de la aplicación hace referencia a objetos grandes durante demasiado tiempo o intenta procesar grandes cantidades de datos a la vez. Los problemas también podrían existir en bibliotecas de terceros utilizadas dentro de una aplicación.

Mi consejo es que debugees y encuentres el lugar donde te está lanzando el error y así poder tratarlo y cambiarlo acorde a como necesites.Puedes también meterlo todo en un try catch(OutOfMemoryError ex) de manera que puedes controlar el error y esa salida.